# Print through SSH

Tags: linux, printing, ssh

I am trying to print on my lab's computer FROM my local computer through SSH. One option is to log in in the remote machine and then to print using lp, i.e.

```
ssh me@mylab.com
```

and once in the remote computer do `lp file.pdf`. It does work. But what I want is to run a small script such that it automatically prints a LOCAL file (in my computer) in the remote printer installed in the REMOTE machine. So I can make an alias (or function) to print straight a file located in my computer through the lab's printer. I tried

```
ssh me@mylab.com lp local_path/myfile.pdf
```

and it does not work. It says

```
lp: Command not found.
```

I also tried `ssh -t me@mylab.com lp local_path/myfile.pdf` , and had the same result. What should I do?

Comment: put in the full path for lp, e.g. `ssh ... /usr/bin/lp ...` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood you correctly; does this work?

```
cat myfile.pdf | ssh me@mylab.com "cat - | /path/to/lp"
```

Comment: In what way will this make the other side find `lp`?

Comment: This is the right idea for printing a local file (alternatively, `ssh user@host /path/to/lp - < myfile.pdf` if you're not a cat person). The command not found issue will have to be fixed separately though

Comment: Perhaps using `ssh user@host env PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/user/bin lp - < localfile.pdf` ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - oops. This totally slipped my attention. It won't FIND lp; that's where specifying the /path/to/lp comes in.

Comment: @thatotherguy "If you're not a cat person" :D Right on! Some of us are dog persons

Comment: @thatotherguy - you apparently **completely** missed the point of the command chain. =}

Comment: @tink how do you mean?

Comment: My command does not print a file locally; it cats it through ssh and prints on the remote box.

Comment: @tink It prints a local file on a remote printer, as does my simplified suggestion